# Can access detailed information through URL with function parameters (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, url, parameters

I am creaiting my first Codeigniter application for a blog with news. In the main page there is only the title of the news which is also a link to a view with the detailed information and body of the news. Im having trouble on accessing the get through the URL that has to go over a function that receives the ID of the new as a parameter. I just can get that to work. Can someone help me?

The problem is not in the function itself because it works fine when i assig an static value to the URL, but for some reason i can send the $row->id object as a Get through the URL with the proper value for each of the news.

MODEL

```
class Post extends CI_Model{


    public function getPost(){

        $this->load->database('fintech_blog');
        $data = $this->db->get('post');
        return $data->$result();

    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function getPost($id){

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from post where id = '$id' ");
    $rows = $query->result(); //method for putting into an array format
    $data=array('result'=>$rows);

    $this->load->view('view',$data);

}
```

VIEW

```
foreach ($result as $row): 

$id = $row->id;
$post = site_url('welcome/getPost/$row->id');

?>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="<?php echo $post; ?>">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        <?php echo $row->title; ?>
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        <?php echo $row->calling; ?>
                    </h3>

                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted on
                    <!-- <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> -->
                    <?php echo time_elapsed_string($row->created); ?></p>

                </div>
                <hr>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: In View, $post = site_url('welcome/getPost/$row->id'); here variable will not parse because the use of single quote(''). Replace single quotes('') with double quotes("") and then try.

Comment: You can try this first `$post = site_url('welcome/getPost/' . $row->id);` to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you create the string for `$post`.
As one commenter suggests the problem is the use of single quotes and to use double quotes instead. The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. Meaning the variable symbol (`$test` in this case) is replaced with the value of the variable.

To illustrate:

```
$test = "blue";
//first, a string created with single quotes
echo 'The sky is $test today.';  //outputs: The sky is $test today.
```

But using double quotes to create the string...

```
echo "The sky is $test today.";  //outputs: The sky is blue today.
```

The var `$test` get expanded to the value it holds.

So, the first two lines of the `foreach` loop in the view should be.

```
 $id = $row->id;
 $post = site_url("welcome/getPost/$row->id");
```

However, you never use `$id` and you only use `$post` once. That says to me that these two lines are not needed. Delete them both.

Change the line

```
<a href="<?php echo $post; ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("welcome/getPost/$row->id"); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @DFriend